# Debug = False and static files not applied

Tags: django, static

I am trying to configure my django project
I have the folder organization bellow

my problem is that my styles.css files in not applied
in my understanding, the path in STATICFILES_DIRS is correct but I have a 404 error

> [18/Nov/2019 13:58:01] "GET /static/css/styles.css HTTP/1.1" 404 2377

what I am doing wrong?

```
- static
 - admin
 - django_extensions
- project
 - settings.py
 - monitor
 - randomization
 - registration
 - static
      - css
         - styles.css
      - images
```

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'static'),
)
STATIC_ROOT = 'D:/Users/jl3/DevSpace/static/'
```

Comment: By setting `DEBUG = False`, the static files are not served. Django's static files is used for development purposes. It is not very efficient, an d likely not safe.

Comment: See the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/static-files/#configuring-static-files) for more information.

Comment: If you want them to be served by NGINX, you have to `./manage.py collectstatic` and declare the static alias in the `nginx.conf`